# How to calculate point on circle from angle between middle and other point on the circle

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, point, angle

I have circle with diameter 256px, middle point is on xy[128,128]. I have first point on circle, for example X=0,Y=128. Coordinates origin is in left top corner. Line between first point and middle, together with angle on this line (starting from middle) creates triangle which intersects circle in third point. How can I calculate this point?

Input variables are :

1. point xy on circle
2. middle point
3. angle

expected output is x1,y1

[image]

Comment: In geometry, you usually speak of the 'center', not the 'middle'...

Comment: So you have a circle with centre **C** and a point on the circle **A** and you want to find the point **B** on the circle so that the angle between AC and CB has a given value?

Comment: @MOehm good guess. That makes sense.

Comment: Based on @MOehm 's suspicion (which I share): First translate your coordinates such that center is located at `{0, 0}` (simple subtractions). Then rotating the point in question is achieved by matrix multiplication with `{ {cos(angle), -sin(angle)}, {sin(angle), cos(angle)} }`. Then translate the coordinates back to your desired system (simple additions). See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for details.

Comment: @MOehm yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulas for rotation of initial point around center point by angle:

```
 x1 = middle.x + (x - middle.x) * cos(angle) - (y - middle.y) * sin(angle)
 y1 = middle.y + (x - middle.x) * sin(angle) + (y - middle.y) * cos(angle)
```

(this is affine transform - combination of translation middle to origin, rotation about origin and backward translation)

Don't forget to make cos and sin argument in radians rather than degrees like this:

```
 cos(angle * M_PI / 180)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think it is not working, hope I did not typo. For input parameters xy[0,128] and angle 90 I expected output x1y1[128,0] in clockwise direction. I now get x1=185.353423, y1=13.568427. Do I something wrong?

Comment: What is value of cos(90)? Perhaps you forgot about degrees/radians?

Comment: cos[90]=-0.448074

Comment: cos(90 * M_PI / 180) = 0, the same coefficient should be used for sine

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was not sure that M_PI works everywhere

Comment: @MBo nor am I, but at least `M_PI` is correct C++. +1